# Find expansion coefficients for non-integer rational base 'b' that minimize "$\epsilon$-closeness" to a root

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, machine-precision

For a non-integer rational base *b*, where *b* $\in$ (1,2), and the allowed expansion coefficients/symbols are $d_k$ $\in$ {-1,0,1}, it is known that *b* cannot be a root of the polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^n d_k x^k$. My question relates to how one can determine how "close" *b* can possibly come in terms of it being a solution to the equation $\sum_{k=0}^n d_k x^k = \epsilon$.

Given a finite terminating expansion in *n* terms, with known *n*, and known rational non-integer base *b* $\in$ (1,2), how can one "efficiently" find the coefficients $d_k$ that minimize the absolute value of $\epsilon$?

Furthermore, if *b* is not fixed, how can one efficiently find a non-integer rational *b*, assuming one exists in (1,2), that maximizes the value of this "minimum $d_k$" $\epsilon$ for a fixed *n*?

This may have practical importance in applications where finite terminating representations of numbers in base *b* are known to be unique in the purely mathematical sense, but should be chosen carefully in computer applications given practical limitations on machine precision.

Comment: I guess of nearly equal interest is whether useful bounds can be placed on what the minimum absolute value of $\epsilon$ could be given 'b' and 'n'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n d_k z^k$ be of degree $n$ (so $d_n = \pm 1$).
If $b = x/y$ (in lowest terms),  we must have $|P(b)| \ge y^{-n}$.
This is because
$$ y^n P(b) = \sum_{k=0}^n d_k x^k y^{n-k} \equiv d_n x^n \not\equiv 0 \mod y$$
  It is possible to have equality, e.g. for $b = 3/2$ with $P(z) = z^5 - z^4 - z - 1$ or $P(z) = {z}^{7}-{z}^{6}-{z}^{4}-{z}^{3}+{z}^{2}+z-1$.

Answer (score 0):

For any number of coefficients $ b_{k} $ and $ x^{k} $ with values from some generating function of $ n $,

we can create a series of polynomials

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} b_{k_{n}}x_{n}^{k} = b_{0_{n}} + b_{1_{}}x_{n} + b_{2_{n}}x_{n}^{2} + b_{3_{n}}x_{n}^{3} + ... + b_{k_{n}}x_{n}^{k} = \epsilon_{n} $$

with trivial solutions, and use guassian elimination to determine the minimum value of coefficients $ b_{k} $ for generating function associated with the real cut $ b \in (1,2) $

This way we can find the errors $ \epsilon $ in the solutions for the cut above.

We can then put this polynomial into a composition table of arbitrary size to compute the possible values for $\epsilon_{n} $ for any root by means of the $k^{th}$ difference $\Delta_{k} $ algorithm.

The polynomial for $\epsilon_{n} $ looks like this when you compute the table:

$$ \Delta_{1} = \epsilon_{n} - \epsilon_{n+1} $$

$$ \Delta_{2} = \epsilon_{n} - 2\epsilon_{n+1} - \epsilon_{n+2} $$

$$ \Delta_{3} = \epsilon_{n} - 3\epsilon_{n+1} - 3\epsilon_{n+2} - \epsilon_{n+3} $$

Which can be generalised as a binomial perturbation expansion:

$$ (x - \epsilon)^{n} = C^{n}_{r} \epsilon^{r}x^{n-r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} \epsilon^{r} x^{n-r} $$

Which has an approximation to real solutions in a set of $ 2^{n-1} $ partitions with a residue of $ 2^{-n} $

The choice of floating point precision should be chosen by the latter values of the residue and partitions required to compute the array of $ k^{th} $ differences.

For a 64K computer, I would recommend $ n < 6 $.

Comment: Where do you get a $64K$ computer these days?

Comment: Where is the expression $b = \frac{2n}{2n+1}$ coming from?  The original question specified that $b \in$ (1,2), but for positive integer n, the expression yield b outside this interval... or do we just have too many different "b's" here, and the notation is confusing when 'b' is used to represent both the base, and something else? This is just a completely different set of polynomial coefficients you are constructing that has these coefficients, and they have nothing to do with the base?

Comment: My apologies, that's a mistake on my part, I thought it did. It came from regards to any function that generates an irrational range.
You can pick them up on eBaY and other websites.